# Why do the Andromeda Galaxy images from NASA have some sort of color shifting in it

Tags: galaxy, image-processing

I was checking the images from [this website](https://esahubble.org/images/heic1502a/) of the Andromeda Galaxy.

However, I noticed that [low res images](https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/publicationjpg/heic1502a.jpg) look good, however, the 1.7Gb images has some sort of color shifting in it:[image]

Is there any simple explanation for this? Or is it just normal and the compression to lower res removes it?

**Update**:
Here is the zoomed version on one of the red region (rotated)
[image]

Without annotations:
[image]

Comment: I think this is an interesting question and the answer(s) will prove to be interesting as well, but so far I am not sure you've clearly demonstrated the color difference you're asking about. I assume the image in your post is the "low resolution" version which "looks good"? If so, can you some how find a way to explain why the 1.7 Gb image *does not "look good"?* Without showing the difference you're perceiving it may be difficult to give a good answer, though it's probably easy to speculate that it involves simple averaging...

Comment: Human eyes are great at detecting tiny color differences in close proximity, but they are really really lousy at absolute measurements. Eyes will never tell their owners that a mixture of red green and blue dots  on a black background averages to white, but sure enough if you "zoom out" far enough that's what they will become; if you don't believe that go get a magnifying glass or jeweler's loupe and look closely at your screen! :-)

Comment: @uhoh hi there, I've posted the one with the problem... I'll post a zoom one one of the "correction/shift" to see if it helps

Comment: @uhoh posted, you should now be able to see a sort of horizontal line, which over that line the image is sort of "blue-ish" and below is "yellow-ish"

Comment: Okay great, thank you for your speedy update! If you are able, If you still have it, could you also post that same crop without the arrows/annotation? I'd like to try some amateur statistical analysis of the pixels.

Comment: @uhoh sure, posted

Comment: I can't find the answer, but the image is collected from such a complex patchwork of cameras and filters, I think it can be processing. The weird thing is that they are almost parallel, and there are just two of them and they are irregular sharp edges.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees where does "such a complex patchwork of cameras and filters" come from? Perhaps just one or two extremely well characterized cameras (e.g. the [Hubble Wide Field Camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_Camera_3) 3 and perhaps 2?) and three very carefully chosen standard filters?

Comment: To be honest, I think that you should mail some researchers that have worked on the PHAT image processing and query them about it.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees seems a bit too much for a mere curiosity ahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they are probably processing artefacts, because there are other artefacts there, and because the lines are parallel.

I sent it through RGB saturation and found other artefacts of linear star zones at the seams of some of the images.

The visible color version is only a small element of the PHAT study and perhaps it is not scientifically accurate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: oh was, I wasn't even thinking that the image was a reconstruction of different images taken at different times, this might explain everything

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, sure, it's a mosaic :) https://www.popphoto.com/news/2015/01/check-out-nasas-15-billion-pixel-image-hubble-telescope/ claims it's just shy of 8000 individual images.

Comment: I'm curious why parallel boundaries can't be the result of shear in a spinning disk of inhomogeneous makeup. https://www.eso.org/public/norway/images/potw1938a/?lang The milky way seen from our location is full of reddish filaments of dust that remove blue light. On what basis have you decided that what's seen in the OP's section of the image can not be dust and must be stitching artifacts, something *I have a really hard time believing astronomers are doing?*

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I suspect this is not the correct answer; the author offers no evidence that these aren't dust other than "I think they are probably processing artifacts, because there are other artifacts there, and because the lines are parallel" which does not actually discount dust. Astronomers go through great pains to make these mosaics as scientifically correct as possible, so while possible "I think ESA simply screwed up" is not the most likely possibility. One would have to exclude the other possibilities, including that it's real, first.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Astronomers don't use photoshop, aligning overlapping images can be done to incredible precision as Hubble space telescope's cameras are extremely well characterized and while the motion of individual stars can sometimes be detected, these lanes of dust are not going to be moving or changing brightness substantially over a few years. A few million years yes. But for these purposes everything is effectively standing still with rock-steady brightness. I think you've accepted a wrong or at least a low-quality, unsupported guess of an answer.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Perhaps consider un-accepting and waiting for something more authoritative in a few days or a week or so?

Comment: That's fair enough, although it can't be dust because dust is diffuse and doesn't create 100k ly very sharp line color effects. Here's a list of artefacts, and neither your nor my suggestions is figured precisely on the list. https://illuminateduniverse.org/2021/04/01/image-artifacts/

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees 1) a Stack Exchange answer should do that already, especially when challenging such an effort by ESA astronomers 2) dust is not an artifact, dust is real! 3) "and perhaps it is not scientifically accurate" is pure guesswork and while not impossible, is unlikely considering the source.

Comment: The depth is crowding limited in the optical and NIR, and thus is a strong function of radius. As a result, photometry in the inner bulge fields is far shallower.

Comment: I concur that this is likely the right answer - these look completely like small differences in color balancing from stitching together smaller images.  I suspect that the larger images are balanced *on average*, leading to small discontinuities at the edges. The straightness of the edge is the giveaway that it’s not real.  Regarding “astronomers don’t use Photoshop,” it’s used all the time for public press release images like this one. See [here](https://www.picturecorrect.com/how-hubble-telescopes-iconic-images-are-colorized-in-photoshop/) for example. The science is done on the originals.

Answer (score 3):

Oh! Okay I'm finally getting your question, sorry for being so slow.

We'll wait for a card-carrying astronomer to answer but my guess is that you're seeing either the edge of a thin dust cloud which preferentially scatters & removes blue light, or the edge of a gas cloud that's emitting red light.

With the Python script below I made this image where I "turned off" the stars and then added some additional blurring to visualize the edge better.

[image]

I then selected the range from horizontal pixel numbers 528 to 558 and made a 1D projection of the red, green and blue color channels by averaging across the 30 pixel width chosen to avoid bright stars.

It looks like the edge is defined more by a drop in blue than a rise in red, so I think that the most likely guess is the edge of a dust cloud that's reddening the lower half by scattering blue light from stars behind it away from the line of sight.

One of the (many) challenging things about astronomical observation is that the light you are seeing is not only from the objects you think you're observing, but includes extra light from in front of and behind them, and has light "subtracted" by wavelength-selective absorption by "stuff" between them and you, some of which you only know exists by its absorption.

[image]

Comment: WAW, this is  amazing, thank you so much for the time you took to review my question... do you have any though on why this looks like its "decaying" from left to right? there is also another "shadow" on the left, which makes the image go from (left) yellow, to yellow-blueish, to blue on the right

Comment: the "shift on the right" is more visible on the top part, where you see a kind of switch from red to blue

Comment: The python graph is fantasic and I think you could be right about some near field interference, although it probably isn't a cloud?

Comment: This is information about local dust in the vicinty of Andromeda. It doesn't interact with visible light, is diffuse, smaller, not aligned with the center, and wasn't even documented until about 2018. http://www.deepskycolors.com/archive/2017/01/01/Clouds-Of-Andromeda.html

Comment: What about dust that's *inside and part of Andromeda?*

Comment: Because it's resisting the gravity of andromeda and keeping two straight barriers, it's not swirling like dust does.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees "swirling" moves at astronomical timescales, it's not like we can see it moving or that a few Hubble WFC images of Andromeda are going to look different a few years apart.

Comment: Theres no evidence of swirling from the last 100 million years either, thats strange. You suggest its a uniform thickness straight edge double cloud. Other than that i agree.